# Ajax Datatable How to display data from a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have an Ajax which get data from php file and display in Datatable,it works but when I added function to the php file then my Ajax cannot get data from the file anymore, what should I modify to my Ajax file.

Also, what if I want to change the ajax function to be called depends on the value I post.For example, I have 2 function, A & B, and I will post data called db from the select in my html, if the data is A then Ajax A will be executed.

Can I do this: `$(document ).on('_GET','#db==A',function() {`

**Ajax.js**

```
$(document ).on('click','#showData',function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'table_backend.php',
        mimeType: 'json',
        success: function(data2) {
            var aaData=data2['aaData'];
            $.each(aaData, function(i, data) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.id+ "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.show_activity_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.nasa_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.game_show_id + "</td>";
                body    += "<td>" + data.account_id + "</td>";
                body    += "</tr>";
                $( "#showTable" ).append(body);
            });
            $( "#showTable" ).DataTable();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });
});
```

**table_backend.php**
(My file is too big so I didn't post code about my db)

I added class and function:

```
$t = new table;

if(isset($_POST['db'])){
   if ($_POST['db'] == "show") { $t -> tableShow($connData); }
   if ($_POST['db'] == "show_activity") { $t -> tableShowAc($connData);}
}

class table{
function tableShowAc($connData){
```

My Ajax works before I add function:

```
      ## Read value
      $draw = $_POST['draw'];
      $row = $_POST['start'];
      $rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
      $columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
      $columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
      $columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
      $searchValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connData['conn'],$_POST['search']['value']); // Search value

      ## Search 
      $searchQuery = " ";
      if($searchValue != ''){
         $searchQuery = " and (id like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
         show_activity_id like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
         game_show_id like'%".$searchValue."%' ) ";
      }

      ## Total number of records without filtering
      $sel = mysqli_query($connData['conn'],"select count(*) as allcount from analysis_data.show_activity");
      $records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
      $totalRecords = $records['allcount'];

      ## Total number of record with filtering
      $sel = mysqli_query($connData['conn'],"select count(*) as allcount from analysis_data.show_activity WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery);
      $records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
      $totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

      ## Fetch records
      $empQuery = "SELECT * from analysis_data.show_activity";
      $empRecords = mysqli_query($connData['conn'], $empQuery);
      $data = array();
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
         $data[] = array( 
            "id"=>$row['id'],
            "show_activity_id"=>$row['show_activity_id'],
            "nasa_id"=>$row['nasa_id'],
            "game_show_id"=>$row['game_show_id'],
            "account_id"=>$row['account_id']
         );
      }

      ## Response
      $response = array(
      "draw" => intval($draw),
      "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
      "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
      "aaData" => $data
      );

      echo json_encode($response);
      return json_encode($response);
```

**Html**

```
<label >Select a table:</label>
<select name="db" id="db">
  <option value="">Please select a table</option>
  <option value="show">show</option>
  <option value="show_activity">show_activity</option>
  <option value="show_incentive">show_incentive</option>
  <option value="show_mulp_detail">show_mulp_detail</option>
</select>
<button id="showData" type="submit">Select</button>
</form>

<table id="showTable" class="display dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>show_activity_id</td>
            <td>nasa_id</td>
            <td>game_show_id</td>
            <td>account_id</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to do a bit of debugging first of all, to find out what actually went wrong. Make sure you have proper error reporting enabled, and then check the error log, and see what the response to the AJAX request actually was (browser dev tools, network panel.)

Comment: The code do not have error, just my Ajax suddenly no work like before when I added function to my table_backend.php and I can get that data when I echo the array data.So I wonder how to let Ajax display data from a function.

Comment: Uhm ... your AJAX part is making a GET request, but in the PHP script you are checking whether `$_POST['db']` was set? Looks like your PHP script would not produce any output, if that parameter was not set (and did not contain either `show`or `show_activity`.)

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from your question is, you want to grab data {table data} from php, and you have mentioned you want to grab 2 different data (as you have mentioned A&B)

What I would suggest is to use `post` in ajax and send the parameters to the file, and then handle the request according to the parameters given.

**`but when I added function to the php file then my Ajax cannot get data from the file anymore`**, I don't see any function in php but I think you meant something like this..?

```
<?php
   function something(){
   //data query and search
   echo //the JSON result
   }
?>
```

Here is something you can do with Ajax to get 2 different data.

```
<!-- A simple select in HTML -->
<select name="dbdata" onchange="ajaxCall(this.value)">
   <option > Choose a value </option>
   <option value='a' > A </option>
   <option value='b' > B </option>
</select>
<!-- Script for AJAX call -->
<script>
  //function ajaxCall
  function ajaxCall(val){
     //If you wanna use GET
     $.get("table_backend.php",
     { type : "tabledata", db : val },
     function(data, status){
        if(status == "success"){
           console.log(data);//for debugging purpose
           //Now do your stuff here and fill data in HTML table
        }
        else console.log("Error while getting data from server..!");
     }
     );
     //If you wanna use POST
     //Just use $.post instead of $.get
  }
</script>
```

Now the php { **table_backend.php** }

```
<?php
  //Grab the parameters from request.
  //$_GET or $_POST according to request made from Ajax.
  if(isset($_GET['type'])){
     $type = $_GET['type'];
     $db = $_GET['db'];
  }
  else echo "no parameters..!";
  if($type == "tabledata"){//Just to ensure everything works fine nothing much
     if( $db == 'a' ){
     //Gonna call a function to get data for db=a
     //As you have mentioned you have function in php so call that function here
     getDBdata_A();//function to get DB data for db=a
     }
     else if($db == 'b'){
     getDBdata_B();//function to get DB data for db=b
     }
  }
//Here are function definitions 
getDBdata_A(){
  //Do your stuff here
  //Querying and searching whatever
  echo echo json_encode($response);//The result
}

getDBdata_B(){
  //Do your stuff here
  //Querying and searching whatever
  echo echo json_encode($response);//The result
}
?>
```

Hope this helps in someway...

Feel free to comment down for any queries.